# UINavigatonBar blur with custom color in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I'm looking for solution how make the NavBar in iOS app like on screenshot below:

[image]

You can see that content under NavBar is blurred and NavBar is colored.

When I try to add a NavBar to my project without changing the color everything is ok:

[image]

But after I set the custom color to my NavBar the blurred content under it becomes almost invisible:

[image]

If change the alpha of bar color then content becomes visible but with gray tint:

[image]

How can I get the same result like on Screenshot 1?

Comment: Did you try to set `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack`?

Comment: Great! Андрію, post the answer and I'll check it like correct!

Comment: I've already posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.000 blue:0.502 alpha:1.000];
```

i randomly picked a pink color, (really random.. not because i like pink..)
[image]

and here is how my nav bar looks like

[image]

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom image that has the effect you are looking for. You then could use custom buttons to replicate the navigation. Make sure you remove the check for "Shows Navigation Bar" in Bar Visibility for your navigation controller.